# Определение переменной

Tags: php

```
<script>
var widthBlock = $('#block').width();
document.write(widthBlock);
</script>
```

Как значение, которое выводится `document.write(widthBlock);` поместить в PHP переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменную можно передать в PHP через куку или отправить ajax-запросом. По мне лучше второе. Будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
<script>
var action = 'your_script.php';
var widthBlock = $('#block').width();
$.post(action, {
     var_name: widthBlock
}, function());
</script>
```

Еще такой момент. Чтобы определить от какого пользователя пришла информация в php-скрипт – можно использовать идентификатор сессии PHP. Он одновременно будет храниться и совпадать в PHP-скрипте и в куке браузера.

Подробнее про сессии в PHP: http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=070

Библиотека для работы с куками из JS: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Причем тут сессия и ваш пример?)

Comment: Если задачей стоит просто передавать ширину блока переменной в php-скрипт (например для сбора статистики по отображению страницы у пользователей), то можно сессии не использовать. Если же нужно сделать определенное действие для определенного пользователя с определенной шириной блока - нужно использовать любой уникальный идентификатор этого пользователя. Я предложил идентификатор сессии (если например у сайта нет системы авторизации или любого другого механизма однозначного определения пользователя).

Comment: Я понимаю для чего нужны сессии и все прочее. Желательно описывать ваши изречения в ответе. Можно много чего использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего случая идеально подходит данное решение:

```
var widthBlock = $('#block').width();
window.location.href = "index.php?widthBlock=" + widthBlock;
```

Для получения значения **widthBlock**, вам нужно обратиться к переменной **$_GET['widthBlock']** в файле index.php